# Обработать 0 rows в запросе к PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Привет. Как обработать запрос к PostgreSQl, если он вернул 0 rows? Например, я делаю запрос:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = {$id}
```

В командной строке `psql` возвращает:

> ### data
>
> (0 rows)

И я бы хотел сделать `echo 'No data found by ID ' . $id;`

UDP: @OlivianSuero, не работает:

```
if (!$result) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        "error" => true,
        "description" => "Data not exists",
    ));
} else {
    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
    echo json_encode($row[0], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

В случае, если запрашиваю несуществующий ID, то возвращается null.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Можно проверить количество возвращаемых `row`:

```
if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");

if (!$result) {
  echo "Произошла ошибка.\n";
  exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "Автор: $row[0]  E-mail: $row[1]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Что-то у меня не очень оно работает. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Потому что пустой результат — тоже результат, а никакая не ошибка.